# How to compare a value to a range in SAS or R

Tags: r, sas

I have a csv file, a small part of which is

```
Optimal
value     7.35-7.45  4.5-8   5.6-7.9    0
ID         V1        V2      V3         V4
1          7.1       5.5     7.6        218
10         7.8       4.8     6.3        407
50         7.12      5.2     5.4        140
```

(Data altered bcs. of confidentiality)

Overall there are 125 subjects and about 50 variables

I need to create, for each variable, the absolute value of the distance between the value and the range. So, e.g. for ID 1:

```
V1dist = abs(7.1 - 7.35) = .25
V2dist = 0 because 4.5 < 5.5 < 8
V3dist = 0 because 5.6 < 7.6 < 7.9
V4dist = 218 because the optimal value is 0
```

Some values are within the ranges - they should get 0. Some are lower, some are higher.

So, I have two problems: 1) How to read in the data 2) How to create the new variables

I have access to SAS and R (and Excel, but....)

Comment: Re (1), in what form are the data now? Your vector of ranges could simply be typed into R pretty easily: `value.min = c(7.35, 4.5, ...)`; `value.max = c(7.45, 8, ...)`. As for the rest of the data, if it were in a tab-delimited text file, [?read.table](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) provides the basic functionality.

Comment: the data are in a csv file.

Comment: Is everything in a csv file? I think it would be easiest if only the data matrix `ID  V1 ...` were in a csv file, and then `value` were in another csv file, or typed in manually. For csv files, you can read them in using `read.table()` w/ `sep=","` or by using [?read.csv](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html).

Comment: Can you revise your question and show an example of the output data set you want?  I'm guessing you want four new variables but it's not clear to me what values they should have.  In other words, is the result you show for **v1dist** using the value of **V1** and the first part of that range "7.35-7.45"?

Comment: Also, to be clear, you say it is a csv but the example has no commas.  Please show the exact top rows of the file.

Comment: Everything is a csv file.  There aren't commas because I copied from Excel rather than a text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution. First of all I read and format the data. I read The matrix skipping the first line (range one) then I read one line(This can be optimized using readLines).

```
dat <- read.table(text='value     7.35-7.45  4.5-8   5.6-7.9    0
ID         V1        V2      V3         V4
1          7.1       5.5     7.6        218
10         7.8       4.8     6.3        407
50         7.12      5.2     5.4        140',header=TRUE,skip=1)
mm <- as.matrix(dat[,-1])
rownames(mm) <- dat[,1]
rngs <- read.table(text='value     7.35-7.45  4.5-8   5.6-7.9    0
ID         V1        V2      V3         V4
1          7.1       5.5     7.6        218
10         7.8       4.8     6.3        407
50         7.12      5.2     5.4        140',nrows=1)
rngs <- lapply(unclass(rngs[1,-1]),
       function(x)as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x),'-'))))
names(rngs) <- colnames(mm)

 mm
     V1  V2  V3  V4
1  7.10 5.5 7.6 218
10 7.80 4.8 6.3 407
50 7.12 5.2 5.4 140
> rngs
$V1
[1] 7.35 7.45

$V2
[1] 4.5 8.0

$V3
[1] 5.6 7.9

$V4
[1] 0
```

Then I compare value to the range. I loop over each column, and using an  nested `ifelse` I compute the range. Note the case I don't have a range , I repeat the same value.

```
sapply(names(rngs),function(x)
{
  vec <- mm[,x]
  inter <- rngs[[x]]
  if(length(inter)==1) inter <- rep(inter,2)
  ## within interval
  ifelse(mm[,x] < inter[2] & mm[,x] > inter[1],
         0,ifelse(mm[,x] > inter[2], mm[,x]-inter[2], inter[1]-mm[,x]))

})

     V1 V2  V3  V4
1  0.25  0 0.0 218
10 0.35  0 0.0 407
50 0.23  0 0.2 140
```

Comment: @PeterFlom you are welcome.  I doubt you get better SAS solution:)

Comment: @gung :) sorry for my Englsih. It is a French word to say `imbricated` or `nested ifelse`.

Comment: No problem, @agstudy, I'm always impressed w/ people who can discuss technical things in >1 language (my wife is Dutch, she knows 10 languages ;-). FWIW, I didn't know "imbricated" (in English) either; Google tells me it means "arranged... so that they overlap like roof tiles".